# How can I patch ubuntu 19.04 kernel adding FTE0001 to focaltech.c so that my focaltech touchpad can work properly

Tags: focaltech

Output of

```
dmesg | grep PNP
```

```
[    0.268113] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[    0.271227] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
[    0.377020] system 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.377264] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.377358] system 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT3f0d PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.378720] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
[    0.378808] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs FTE0001 PNP0f13 (active)
[    0.379404] system 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.379529] system 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.380283] system 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.383270] system 00:08: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    1.454077] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:19/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
[    1.454191] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
[    1.454252] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input2
[    1.488961] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[   15.074160] input: Intel HID events as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT33D5:00/input/input7
[   15.074244] input: Intel HID 5 button array as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT33D5:00/input/input8
[   15.947074] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input9
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Which change to the kernel are you suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit3:**

- Two Finger scrolling Working
- Tap to Click working
- Edge Scrolling working
- Pinch to Zoom can be enabled with external tools

Kinetic Scrolling is client side, that means apps developed with support for it work fine, most GNOME apps support it. I tested GNOME web (epiphany) and it works perfectly.

source:
[github.com/chilledHamza/focaltech-dkms](https://github.com/chilledHamza/focaltech-dkms)

Comment: Can you share the build.

Comment: [chilledHamza/focaltech-dkms](https://github.com/chilledHamza/focaltech-dkms)

Comment: Thanks its working now but cursor movement seems way too much accelerated other then nice work hope you get it merge in kernel.

Comment: How can I install it?

Comment: `sudo dkms add ./focaltech-dkms
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/.-focaltech-dkms does not exist.`

Comment: i'm not sure what you are doing wrong. Screenshot of terminal window might help.